# How do I make the default response Content-type: application/json with Scalatra

Tags: scala, scalatra

I'm learning Scalatra and am wondering how I can make the default Content-Type of my responses `application/json`.  The current default appears to be `text/html`.  Neat, but not really useful to my application.

The current default is `text/html`.

```
$ curl -i -X GET 'http://localhost:8080/v1/example'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 19 Apr 2019 07:21:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 23
Server: Jetty(9.4.8.v20171121)

HelloWorld(hello,world)
```

I can get `application-json` explicitly through the `Accepted: application/json` header.

```
$ curl -i -X GET 'http://localhost:8080/v1/example' -H 'Accept: application/json'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 19 Apr 2019 07:22:09 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(9.4.8.v20171121)

{"hello":"hello","world":"world"}
```

How do I set the default to be `application/json`.

Comment: How do you generate the response? Simply by returning a string that contains a json? If you would be using proper types then it scalatra should be able to figure out the content type as here: https://github.com/swagger-api/scalatra-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/wordnik/swagger/sample/PetServlet.scala

Comment: @michaJlS Scalatra is bright enough to know how to deal with a case class.  It is already doing that, if the client requests `-H Accept: application/json` scalatra takes the case class and make the JSON string.  That works great.  The problem is, I want the default to just be `Content-Type: application/json`.  Scalatra doesn't make that so convenient.  There has to be a way.

Comment: So this link then should be helpful: http://scalatra.org/guides/2.3/formats/json.html

Comment: @michaJlS Thanks, but I'm way past that.  The `before() { contentType = formats("json") }` indeed sets the contentType for the Servlet as constant `application/json`, so if someone requests `text/html`, they don't get it.  All I'm trying to do is override the default in the absence of an `Accepts` header.  It is surprising that it is so difficult to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`defaultFormat`](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra/blob/42ed00309b32d9c4bf0ed68035a2aa376b475c69/core/src/main/scala/org/scalatra/ApiFormats.scala#L84) could be overridden to make `application/json` the default case. For example,

```
import java.io.File
import org.scalatra._
import org.scalatra.util.MimeTypes
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, Formats}
import org.scalatra.json._

case class HelloWorld(hello: String, world: String)

class MyScalatraServlet extends ScalatraServlet with JacksonJsonSupport {
  protected implicit lazy val jsonFormats: Formats = DefaultFormats

  override def defaultFormat: Symbol = 'json

  get("/v1/example") {
    HelloWorld("hello", "world")
  }

}
```

without specifying `Accept` header should respond with

```
curl -i -X GET 'http://localhost:8080/v1/example'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 25 Apr 2019 22:28:37 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 33
Server: Jetty(9.4.8.v20171121)

{"hello":"hello","world":"world"}
```

whilst explicitly requesting `Accept: text/html` also works

```
curl -i -X GET 'http://localhost:8080/v1/example' -H 'Accept: text/html'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 26 Apr 2019 15:45:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 23
Server: Jetty(9.4.8.v20171121)

HelloWorld(hello,world)
```

Comment: @"Mario Galic".  Cool, but....obscure?  I was kind-of expecting something more along the lines of `override def defaultFormat = formats("json")` or something.  How did you figure this out?  I'm newish to Scala and completely new to Scalatra and am trying to find my way in this "ecosystem".

Comment: I searched for term `Accept` in Scalatra Github repo to see how the header gets used which led me to `ApiFormats.scala`.